# Grouping points with distance using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have a point layer and I want to create polygons arround points which are in distance of 10 meters.

I did create a grid vector of 10m but it doesn't group as well as they have to be.

I did create a buffer arround my points in arcgis, as you know arcgis buffer tool gives you the posiibility to choose a dissolve type yet in the merged buffers I can have also a point which is in a distance of 20m.

I'm wondering if there is a possibility, using ArcGIS Desktop, to select from the same layer the features within a distance of  10m  and create a polygon around.